# How many inodes I need?

Tags: linux, filesystems, disk-space, inode

I'm running a Buildroot image that has not the `-i` flag for `df`. I have near 100 MB of free space, but when I try to add a nodejs module using `npm install` I get the error `"no free space left"`.

I guess it could be related to inodes rather than phisical spaces.
In Buildroot I can set the number of extra inodes I want.

Two questions:

1. without the `-i` flag, is there another way to be sure if I ran out of inodes?
2. how to calculate how many extra inodes I need?

Comment: For the first question I found: tune2fs -l /dev/x

Comment: Is it possible to copy the whole contents of your fs to another fs where  `df -i` is available and count the increase in inodes being used?

Comment: As said, now I'm able to "count" the inodes using tune2fs. But how to design a system with the "right" number of inodes?